# Flutter stomp client cant connect with spring stomp client

Tags: java, spring, flutter, dart, stomp

I,m new in Flutter. I'm trying to connect to spring websocket which uses stomp but the connection fails. I'm using stomp_dart_client 0.3.3. Spring sever is working fine. I'm able to see the messages on the browser.

This is my spring implementation:

Spring config class:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}
```

Spring controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

Flutter implementation:

```
StompClient stompClient = StompClient(
        config: StompConfig(
          url: 'ws://10.0.2.2:7000',
          onConnect:(ss, dd)=> ss.subscribe (
            destination: '/topic/greetings/gs-guide-websocket',
            callback: (StompFrame frame) {
              print(frame.body);
            },
          ),
          onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
          onStompError: (d) => print("stomp error"),
          onDisconnect: (d)=> print("disconnect"),
        ));

   stompClient.activate();

   stompClient.subscribe (
        destination: '/topic/greetings',
        callback: (StompFrame frame) {
          print(frame.body);
          List<dynamic> result = json.decode(frame.body);
          return result;
        },
    );
```

this is the error:

```
E/flutter (30825): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(213)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (30825): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'subscribe' was called on null.
E/flutter (30825): Receiver: null
E/flutter (30825): Tried calling: subscribe(callback: Closure: (StompFrame) => List<dynamic>, destination: "/topic/greetings", headers: null)
E/flutter (30825): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (30825): #1      StompClient.subscribe (package:stomp_dart_client/stomp.dart:74:21)
E/flutter (30825): #2      _MyHomePageState._receivedMessage (package:tutorial_projecect/main.dart:154:16)
E/flutter (30825): #3      _MyHomePageState.build (package:tutorial_projecect/main.dart:90:41)
E/flutter (30825): #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
E/flutter (30825): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
E/flutter (30825): #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (30825): #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #8      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4707:5)
E/flutter (30825): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (30825): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #14     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4583:5)
E/flutter (30825): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (30825): #21     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (30825): #22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #23     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4707:5)
E/flutter (30825): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (30825): #30     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (30825): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4707:5)
E/flutter (30825): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (30825): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #36     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4583:5)
E/flutter (30825): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (30825): #39     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (30825): #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (30825): #41     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4707:5)
E/flutter (30825): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3201:15)
E/flutter (30825): #43     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5837:14)
E/flutter (30825): #44     Element.updateCh
```

Answer (score 2):

Pulling this back to the original post which mentioned stomp_dart_client, I struggled to find working examples for this on the internet and Stack Overflow, so here's my solution that may help.

I am using RabbitMQ with the Web STOMP plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html, publishing JSON packets onto a queue called "ping".  The examples and the documents for stomp_dart_client were not clear regarding how to connect to a secure session, to which I have resolved by adding authentication within the header:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp.dart';
import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp_config.dart';
import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp_frame.dart';

dynamic onConnect(StompClient client, StompFrame frame) {
  client.subscribe(
      destination: 'ping',
      callback: (StompFrame frame) {
        var jsonData = json.decode(frame.body);
        print(jsonData);
      });
}

final stompClient = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig(
        url: 'ws://x.x.x.x:15674/ws',
        onConnect: onConnect,
        onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
        stompConnectHeaders: {
      'login': 'someuserlogin',
      'passcode': 'somepassword'
    },
));

void main() {
  stompClient.activate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation and retries I found the issue.
registerStompEndpoints should not return SockJs.

And i have used another stomp lib: stomp: ^0.8.0

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sed! I'm new to Flutter too and I'm trying to do exactly what you did. Did you follow any tutorial that you could send me? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeOliveira, I followed this one here and it is fine now with Flutter stomp client.

https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_dart_client/example

Answer (score 1):

### Firstly.

Your original post should use `stompClient.subscribe` in the onConnect callback. If you subscribe before connected, the client object is null.

### Secondly.

Since you changed a lib. You should show your new code. I have tried both lib. And stomp: ^0.8.0 gives

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [STOMP0x0aaccept-version:1.20x0a0x0a...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

Still struggle to make it work...